# Databases and Multi-Column Indexes (mySQL)

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm working with a table that has what seems like a lot of indexes - 8 in fact. But some of them seem redundant, for example, here's a few of these indexes:

```
type     columns
-----    ------------------------------
index    project_id
unique   project_id, user_id, event_id
index    project_id, user_id, type, subtype
```

Now, from what I know, the unique one is necessary because its preventing duplicates of combinations of those three keys, and we require that. However, isn't the first index unnecessary?

I did a quick `select * from activities where project_id = 5579` and it used the index with 4 columns ( based on Explain ). With another query, simply changing the project_id, it used the unique index. Will there be situations where the first index is still used, or can I safely remove it?

This situation also holds true of the user_id column - its indexed by itself, and then has multi-column indexes where its the first column.

My understanding is more indexes = slower inserts, so I'm thinking I should try to remove unnecessary ones.

Comment: So is the table suffering from slow inserts? Is it breaking anything? The problem here is that these indexes might have been created for slow running queries and by removing them you will create another problem. Remember if it aint broke dont fix it.

Comment: @Namphibian The table gets about 30 inserts a second, so making it better would be a good thing. I believe that removing the first index would not affect any queries that would have relied on it, due to the 2nd and 3rd index, but I'm looking for verification of that from someone who may know more then I do.

Comment: Your thinking is correct. Could we see all the indexes. It is probably over indexed. Can you identify all the queries that are issued against this table?

Answer (score 0):

The index `project_id, user_id, type, subtype` covers the case when a WHERE or GROUP BY specifies just `project`_id by itself.

Answer (score 0):

One of the key things to note about compound indexes is that the order of the fields listed in the index matters.

So for your index `project_id, user_id, event_id` you can only use this index if one of the following conditions is met:

`project_id` is used in WHERE, GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or JOIN condition
OR
`project_id` AND `user_id` are used in WHERE, GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or JOIN condition
OR
`project_id` AND `user_id` AS `event_id` are used in WHERE, GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or JOIN condition

If you tired to use `user_id` or `event_id` by themselves, the index would not be used. If you tried to use `user_id` and `event_id` the index would not be used.  If you tried to use `project_id` and `event_id` the index would not be used.

So to answer your question the `index_id` index is likely not needed here is you are going to use `index_id` by itself`.

You of course must have a full understanding of all the possible ways in which a table may be queried in order to understand which indexes are required, and which would not be needed.